# "The Post Content Widget was not found in your template." (Elementor)

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am getting below alert while trying to edit a Page or a Post using the **Elementor** Plugin

[image: e]

Answer (score -2):

**Post content** widget must be enabled to use Single Post Template, after that you need to  set page layout to default. In that case everything edited in Single Post template will be delivered as default post content and you can edit everything else that was not set up in single post template.

You can also click the **Edit Template** button when you get this error and Drag the **Post content** widget. After saving the changes you should be able to edit using **Elementor**.